# Confused with ripple carry adder output

Tags: verilog

I am working on a ripple carry adder using structural verilog, which is supposed to take in two random inputs and calculate accordingly.

The general rca I created calculated correctly, but for some reason I get weird outputs when I add a for loop and use the `$random` to generate.

Could someone kindly explain where I'm going wrong? Below is my code:

```
module full_adder(x,y,z,v,cout);
    parameter delay = 1;

    input x,y,z;    //input a, b and c
    output v,cout;  //sum and carry out

    xor #delay x1(w1,x,y);
    xor #delay x2(v,w1,z);
    and #delay a1(w2,z,y);
    and #delay a2(w3,z,x);
    and #delay a3(w4,x,y);
    or #delay o1(cout, w2,w3,w4);
endmodule

module four_bit_adder(a,b,s,cout,cin);//four_bit_adder
    input [15:0] a,b;       //input a, b
    input cin;              //carry in
    output [15:0] s;        //output s
    output cout;            //carry out
    wire [15:0] c;


    full_adder fa1(a[0],b[0],cin,s[0],c0);  
    full_adder fa2(a[1],b[1],c0,s[1],c1);
    .
    .
    .
    full_adder fa16(a[15],b[15],c14,s[15],cout); 
endmodule



module testAdder(a,b,s,cout,cin);
    input [15:0] s;         
    input cout;             
    output [15:0] a,b;      
    output cin;             
    reg [15:0] a,b;
    reg cin;
    integer i;
    integer seed1=4;
    integer seed2=5;
    initial begin
         for(i=0; i<5000; i=i+1) begin
            a = $random(seed1);
            b = $random(seed2);
            $monitor("a=%d, b=%d, cin=%d, s=%d, cout=%d",a,b,cin,s,cout);
            $display("a=%d, b=%d, cin=%d, s=%d, cout=%d",a,b,cin,s,cout);
            end
    end            
endmodule
```

Here are two lines from the output that I get:

```
a=38893, b=58591, cin=x, s=    z, cout=z
a=55136, b=58098, cin=x, s=    z, cout=z
```

Comment: The `'z` is coming from somewhere within your adder or possibly your top level module so without that code, we cant help. As for `cin`, you never assign it a value. Also, two things. First, you can throw the `$monitor` out to the beginning of the loop and don't need to call it again (you can also then get rid of the `$display`). Also, you need to add a delay into your loop or it will just run the 5000 times all at once, allowing your module only to see the last output (ie, `a = ... ; b = ... ; #10;` should be the loop body)

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using a for-loop in verilog. Also I've edited the code above and added the missing modules

Answer (score 2):

This is a *combinational circuit*, so the output changes **instantaneously** as the input changes. But, here you are apply all the inputs at **same timestamp** which should **not** be done since the `full_adder` module provides **1-timestamp delay**. This may not cause problems in this module, but may cause issues while modelling sequential logic. Add a minimum of `#10` delay between inputs.

Also, `$monitor` executes on **each change in the signal list**, so no need to use it in `for` loop. Just initialize `$monitor` in `initial` condition.

`cin` is also not driven from the testbench. Default value of `reg` is `'x` and that of `wire` is `'z`. Here, `cin` is `reg`, so the default value is displayed, that is `'x`

One more thing, you must **instantiate** the design in your testbench. And connect respective ports. The outputs from testbench act as inputs to your design and vice-versa. This is just like you instantiate `full_adder` module in `four_bit_adder` module in design.

Consider `testadder` as **top level module** and instantiate design in it. **No** need of declaring **ports** as input and output in this module. Declare the design **input ports** as `reg` or `wire`(example: `reg [15:0] a` when `a` is design input port) and **output ports** as `wire` (example: `wire [15:0] sum` when `sum` is design input port).

Referring to your question:

> The general rca I created calculated correctly, but for some reason I get weird outputs when I add a for loop and use the $random to generate.

Instead of using `$random`, use `$urandom_range()` to generate random numbers in some **range**. Using SystemVerilog constraints constructs can also help. Refer [this](http://www.testbench.in/CR_03_SYSTEMVERILOG_CRV.html) link.

Using `$urandom_range` shall eliminate use of `seed1` and `seed2`, it shall generate random values with some random machine seed.

Following is the module testadder with some of the changes required:

```
module testAdder();
    wire [15:0] s;         
    wire cout;             
    // output [15:0] a,b;      
    // output cin;             
    reg [15:0] a,b;
    reg cin;
    integer i;
    integer seed1=4;
    integer seed2=5;

   // Instantiate design here
   four_bit_adder fa(a,b,s,cout,cin);

    initial begin
         // Monitor here, only single time
         $monitor("a=%d, b=%d, cin=%d, s=%d, cout=%d",a,b,cin,s,cout);
         for(i=0; i<5000; i=i+1) begin
            // Drive inputs with some delays.
            #10;
            // URANDOM_RANGE for input generation in a range
            a = $urandom_range(0,15);
            b = $urandom_range(0,15);
            // a = $random(seed1);
            // b = $random(seed2);
            // Drive cin randomly.
            cin = $random; 
            $display("a=%d, b=%d, cin=%d, s=%d, cout=%d",a,b,cin,s,cout);
            end
    end            
endmodule
```

For more information, have a look at sample testbench [at this link](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day4.html).

Comment: Note that you dont NEED to instantiate your module inside the testbench (though its the style I prefer). You can also have the testbench be a module as he has and you instantiate and hookup the testbench and the DUT in a top level module (which will have no inputs or outputs usually). Many tutorials/textbooks and such go for this second model, so thats probably where his design comes from. Either your fix or creating a top level module will fix his disconnected issue.

Comment: @Unn From what I get, I think you are referring to [this](http://www.testbench.in/vlogintf.PNG) type of architecture. Here, I have considered top module and testbench in a single module itself, considering the lesser coding perspective. I think both approaches are similar except the wrapper around the environment. Though, any design engineer shall prefer your approach, verification engineer may prefer to use the other one.

Comment: I am and I prefer the style you have above. Im just noting the other style might be what the asker was going for :)